# If a problem A in NP is reducible in polyomial time to a problem B, can one say that B must also be in NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability

In other words:

If $A \leq_{p} B$ and $A \in NP \Rightarrow B \in NP$

From my deduction this is has to be false. We know that if $A$ is NP Complete $\Rightarrow A$ NP-Hard and $A \in NP$, then $B$ is NP-Hard but we can't say for sure that $B \in NP$.

I struggle to understand why though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to give you some kind of image you can use to build your intuition:

Think of the problems and the complexity classes, as boxes and shipping containers of different shapes and sizes. Translate $A \leq_p B$ to "box $A$ fits into box $B$", and translate $A \in \mathrm{NP}$ to "box $A$ fits into shipping container $\mathrm{NP}$".

If you know that

- box $A$ fits into box $B$, and that
- box $A$ fits into shipping container $\mathrm{NP}$,

can you conclude that box $B$ fits into shipping container $\mathrm{NP}$? You can't, right? Box $B$ might be too big or weirdly shaped to fit in there.

Comment: That's actually an amazing answer to build up intuition.

Answer (score 1):

One rough intuition that can help you is: if $A \leq_p B$, then $A$ is "simpler than or equal to" $B$.

The fact that there exists a (polynomial) reduction $A \mapsto B$ tells you that $A$ is either the same problem as $B$ or a special case of it. In this sense, $A \leq_p B$ does not tell you anything about $B$ in general.

In a case such as $SAT \leq B$, however, you know that $SAT$ is $\mathcal {NP}$-Hard, which means (using the intuition above) that every problem in $\mathcal{NP}$ is "simpler" than $SAT$. By the transitive property of $\leq$, it is immediate that every $\mathcal {NP}$  problem is also "simpler" than $B$, which means that $B$ is $\mathcal{NP}$-Hard as well.

If, additionally, we knew that $B$ is in $\mathcal{NP}$, we could conclude that it is $\mathcal{NP}$-complete.

Answer (score 1):

Any $B$ such that $B$ is $\text{NP}$-hard but not $\text{NP}$-complete suffices as a counterexample. By definition, any $A\in\text{NP}$ can be reduced to such a $B$ in polynomial time.

One choice for $B$ would be the Halting-Problem $H$. Clearly $H\not\in\text{NP}$, though $H$ is $\text{NP}$-hard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I know how to prove this with by contradiction, but I do not understand intuitively why this stands without just giving a circular definition of what is already known.

Answer (score 1):

If you can reduce A in polynomial time to B then B might be much more difficult than A, including being much harder. “Polynomial reduction” means if you can solve the B instance then you get a solution for the A instance, so the harder B is, the easier it will be to reduce A to B.

It may be possible that the instances of B that you create by reducing instances of A are all in NP, but that might not be helpful.